# Ошибка 6 (неверный дескриптор) - в чём причина?

Tags: c++, winapi

Для начала мне требуется найти некоторый файл:

```
HANDLE hExample4;
HANDLE hExample24;
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
hExample4 = FindFirstFile("Example4.bin",&fd);
hExample24 = FindFirstFile("Example24.bin",&fd);
```

Так вот, после того, как я начинаю работать с этими дескрипторами, вызов любой функции типа `SetEndOfFile()`, `GetFileSize()` и т. д. выдаёт ошибку, а при вызове `GetLastError()` можно увидеть, что это ошибка 6 (неверный дескриптор).

Что тут не так?

Comment: Если Вы получили удовлетворяющий Вас ответ, пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку рядом с этим ответом, чтобы принять его.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FindFirstFile` возвращает *дескриптор поиска*(не тот дескриптор, который создается при открытии файла с помощью функции `CreateFile`, назовем его *файловый дескриптор*). Поэтому вы его не можете использовать в функциях для работы с файлами типа `SetEndOfFile, GetFileSize`.
*Дескриптор поиска* вы можете использовать только для дальнейшего поиска других файлов с помощью функции `FindNextFile`.

> Когда *дескриптор поиск*а больше не нужен, вы его должны закрыть с помощью
>   функции `FindClose`, именно с помощью этой функции, а не с помощью
>   функции `CloseHandle`, который мы закрываем *файловый дескриптор*, когда создаем
>   его с помощью функции `CreateFile`

Поэтому если вы нашли этот файл, то для получения *файлового дескриптора* вызовите функцию `CreateFile` с флагом `OPEN_EXISTING`, если вам он действительно нужен.

P.S Функция `FindFirstFile` возвращает структуру `LPWIN32_FIND_DATA`, из которой вы можете получить размер файла во так

```
LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
filesize.LowPart = fd.nFileSizeLow;
filesize.HighPart = fd.nFileSizeHigh;
_tprintf(TEXT("  %s   %ld bytes\n"), fd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
```

[FindFirstFile Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)
[Listing the Files in Directory Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

нужно проверить результаты функции поиска. По MSDN

```
 hFind = FindFirstFile(filename, &FindFileData);
   if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   {

      printf ("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      return;

   }
```

Comment: Нет, дело оказалось не в этом. Похоже, дескриптор, полученный в результате поиска, нельзя использовать в других ситуациях, и для этого следует использовать `CreateFile()` с параметром `OPEN_EXISTING`.